# conda meta.yaml requirements run section dependencies from file

Tags: conda, conda-build

In meta.yaml file we have requirements->run section wherein dependent runtime packages are defined in the format:

```
requirements:
  run:
    - python
    - p1
    - p2
```

Is it possible to specify these dependencies as part of a file like requirements.txt and reference it in meta.yaml file.

Answer (score 4):

You can read files like `pyproject.toml` and `requirements.yml` (where I put my unpinned top-level dependencies):

```yaml
{% set pyproject = load_file_data("../pyproject.toml", from_recipe_dir=True) %}
{% set requirements = load_file_data("../requirements.yml", from_recipe_dir=True) %}

requirements:
  host:
    {% for dep in pyproject["build-system"]["requires"] %}
    - {{ dep.lower() }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for dep in requirements["dependencies"] %}
    - {{ dep.lower() }}
    {% endfor %}
  run:
    {% for dep in requirements["dependencies"] %}
    - {{ dep.lower() }}
    {% endfor %}
```

(Note that I'm not 100% sure whether I'm using the sections in `requirements:` correctly, but this way it works for me.)

Comment: Your example with the parameter `from_recipe_dir` just saved my day, thanks!

Comment: The above's load_file_data has missing closing parentheses. And is it really working? I've been trying to get just the name of the project from pyproject, but apparently the pyproject dictionary object made by jinja template is empty. My layout is root/pyproject.toml and root/conda.recipe/meta.yml @flotzilla, how did you solve this?

Comment: @Adji_PA Good catch regarding the missing closing parens, thanks, I've fixed it. This has indeed been working for me for a while now, and as far as I can tell also should work in your layout. The only difference to mine are that my file is called `meta.yaml` (note the suffix) and resides in `recipe/` (no period), which SHOULD not make a difference but you never know. Otherwise, maybe it's a package version issue, I'm currently using `jinja2=3.1.2`.